# Edible Desert Plant

Tags: identification, desert

I came across this very interesting looking plant while browsing the Internet. Apparently, it is edible (seeds, plants, and maybe the pod), but I just can't find the name of it. It grows in the desert, but I'm not sure exactly where.

Here are some pictures of the plant:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here are pictures of the pod:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here's a picture of the seeds:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on a Google image search it seems to be glossonema edule, and is found in and around Qatar.

Comment: Thanks! I tried using Google image search to no avail. What search parameters did you use to find it?

Comment: I just clicked on a couple of the pics, chose google image search, then started clicking the links that looked the most promising.